# xcode basic game template

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates, xcode-template

I am wondering if anyone knows of a open source or paid Xcode template.
It would be for a basic game, **( NOT COCOS2d )**.
It would include simple items like profile management, load/save, Menu, Settings, 
( perhaps include Openfeint/Game Center )

Something to use as a base for creating new games, things that get used over and over.
I am thinking about creating either a simple match three game, or maybe a card game.

Before I sat down and created one myself, I thought I would check to see if something
was available.  ( No need to recreate the wheel right? )

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why do you want something that is non-Cocos2D?

Comment: I am not interested in learning a new Language right now, also my game does not require it.  it's going to be a simple word or card game.  Simple UIViews with standard UIButtons.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't quite the solution you're looking for as it's not a game template, but it's worth checking out [Sparrow](http://www.sparrow-framework.org/) - it's an open-source Objective C library so you don't need to learn anything new (unlike COCOS2D) and there's a nice [Beginners Action Game tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2010/08/beginners-iphone-action-game-tutorial/) you can follow.

Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Cocos2D I guess you are thinking of 3D i.e. OpenGL ES games. If so, have a look at former question [Alternative of Unity & SIO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438780/alternative-of-unity-sio2). Maybe this is what you are looking for, but you should take SIO2 and Unity3D themselves into consideration. Especially Unity3D (I am just evaluating it the last 2 weeks) will save you a lot of work. SIO2 is a library using Blender for design and ships with customized exporter. It was open source since V1.4 but then they "convert" it into commercial software. What a pitty that the 1.4 source code is still not available at the according SF [project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sio2sdk3dgameen/).

There are two more engines: [Unreal 3 Engine](http://www.unreal.com/) and [Torque](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-2d/iphone). I failed to find the pricing for Unreal now, but it might be something about 25% of your revenue or so. Torque stopped selling their 3D engine on iPhone and is now available in 2D only.

PS: Even for simple games I recommend using some kind of game engine, it will save you a lot of work compared to native XCode hacking.

Comment: Actually I am NOT thinking of 3D,  I would like to create a simple word or card game.  Nothing too fancy, but it would require the standard things most games have.  Profile management, game state save/load, etc..   just the basics.  I am using simple UIViews with buttons and graphics.  So far it seems there is not a BASIC template out there that includes these things that someone could use as a base and then work their game into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this template which is a well researched one available in the market.

http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-boilerplate-and-template/1597