# Alternative of Unity & SIO2

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator, unity-game-engine, sio2

I am searching for open source free API just like Unity or SIO2 which I can use for commercial purpose. Kindly tell me if there is any API for iPhone 3D games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are two open source game engines:

[irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/)

[oolongengine](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/)

I don't know much about irrlicht, but there are some dicussions about it here on stackoverflow.com. I think they support iPhone development for quite a while. oolong seems to have a hard learning curve because there is not much documentation and you have to subscribe to a good old mailing list.

If you are an Indie developer with less than 100k $ / year, [Bork 3D engine](http://bork3d.com/engine) might be worth to look at - you just have to pay $49. There is one drawback in that you don't have support for blender and you should have to check whether collada files are useful, if you don't use a commercial 3D modelling tool.

Just found this in my bookmarks :-) It's a bit out of date but a good place to start investigations:

[iPhone Game Engine Comparison – Open Source](http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison/)

Answer (score 0):

UNREAL

also you can use Unreal game engine which will you help al ot in making high graphics games for iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Being a paid SIO2 user (Android) - My opinion of SIO2 is that the registration scheme on Android is TERRIBLE.

I've had to move on to another product.

The author of SIO2 seems to feel that answering customer questions is beneath him and gives answers in riddle form, as opposed to d